# general topology, subsets and limit points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

> If $A, B$ are nonempty sets, and $A \subset B$, prove that $A' ⊂ B'$.

where $A'$ and $B'$ are the derived sets of $A$ and $B$ respectively

My attempt at the solution is this: let $x$ belong to $A$, then $x$ also belongs to $B$ since $A ⊂ B$. Then $x$ is a limit point to $A$ and thus belongs to $A'$ since $A'$ is the set of all limit points of $A$. And therefore $x$ is also a limit point to $B'$ so $B'$ and $A'$ have the same x and thus $B' \subset A'$.

Please if anyone could improve my proof or make a better one?

Comment: "$A \subset B$" means that $A$ *is contained in* $B$. So "let $x$ belong to $A$, then $x$ also belongs to $B$" is correct, while what you have written, namely "let $x$ belong to $B$, then $x$ belongs to $A$" is incorrect. Also, you need to start with an element of $A'$ and show that it is an element of $B'$, so "then $x$ is a limit point of $B$" seems to come out of nowhere after just having $A \subset B$.

Comment: As @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг pointed out your statement on inclusion is wrong: however you can reverse your argument and considering $x\in A\implies x\in B$ which in turn implies $x\in B'$.

Comment: yes there was a typo, I meant  x∈A⟹x∈B. Can you help me in proving this statement

Comment: Usually you will get many answers for this question. Be sure to check them all out. Up vote whichever ones are good and wait for some time before accepting the best answer you find with the check mark.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is not correct. What you should do is to take an element $x\in A'$ and then to prove that $x\in B'$ (which is easy).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\in A'$. Then, either $x\in A$ or $x$ is a limit point of $A$

---

If $x\in A\subset B\subset B'$, we are clearly done.

If $x$ is a limit point of $A$, there exists a sequence of points $a_1,a_2,...$ such that $\forall i\in\mathbb N,\; a_i\in A,\; d(a_i,x)<\frac1n$. But, $\forall i\in\mathbb N$, $a_i\in B$. Hence, $x$ is also a limit point of $B$, and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

$x\in A'\iff \forall U\in \nu(x), U\cap A_x=\emptyset$ where $U$ is a neighborhood that contain $x$ and $A_x$ means $A\setminus \{x\}$.

---

Let $x\in A'$ and let $U\in \nu(x)$. Then, by definition, $U\cap A_x\neq\varnothing $. But $A_x\subset B_x$. Therefore $U\cap B_x\neq \varnothing $ and thus $x\in B'$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in A'$.

Then for every open set $U$ that contains $x$ there is an element $y\in A\cap U$ with $x\neq y$.

But $A\subset B$ implies that $A\cap U\subset B\cap U$ so that also $y\in B\cap U$.

Proved is now that $x\in B'$ and this is enough.

---

Above $\subset$ is used as a notation for "subset of".